# Google sheets: Increasing count in a field based on non empty in another field

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a sports tournament scorecard in google sheet, and there's a field Total matches with number in it.

- I have a results column with data validation added (list of items) like 3-0, 3-2, so only one value can be selected.
- I want the number of total matches field to increase by 1, every time the results field is 'not empty'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IF(ISBLANK())`:

| Results | Total # of matches |
| --- | --- |
| 3-1 | =1 |
| 2-1 | `=IF(ISBLANK(A3),,B2+1)` |
| 1-1 | `=IF(ISBLANK(A4),,B3+1)` |
|  | `=IF(ISBLANK(A5),,B4+1)` |

So it looks like this:

[image]

Set the first count as 1, then drag down (copy) the formula in the same column to the number of rows as needed.

Comment: Thanks @vtan707. It helped :)
Appreciate it